# Question about when can let $n$ go to infinity

Tags: limits, analysis

Sorry about the typo in the second example and I have already fixed it. I have also changed the first example since this one may be more suitable and it bears a resemblance to the second one.

My question is a bit general. Suppose a proposition is valid for all natural numbers, when can we let $n$ go to infinity and get the result for infinity? I used two examples to clarify, I know how to prove the right part. ****I do not know** the essential difference for them since one can let $n$ go to infinity and the other can not.**

1. Suppose $\forall n, a_n \geq 0$, $x\geq \sum_{1}^{n}a_n$, then we can let $n$ go to infinity to get $x \geq \sum_{1}^{\infty}a_n$ by the property of limit and series.
2. Suppose $\forall i, E_i$ is open set, then $\forall n>0, \cap_{i=1}^{i=n}E_i$ is open set.
   However, we can not let $n$ go to infinity and get $\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}E_i$ is open set.

Comment: Why isn't the infinite union open?  But, to your main point, you answered your question yourself when you wrote "by the property of limit."  In each case, you have to consider whether the limit operation you have in mind makes sense in the given context and whether whatever you are interested in is preserved by passing to a limit.

Comment: Since your question is not about the two examples (you said you know why they are valid), your question is too vague to get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two questions are related. The sets $E_n = \{x\in \mathbb{R} \,:\, x> a - \frac1n\}$ are open and so is any finite intersection of them. But their infinite but countable intersection $E = \{x\in \mathbb{R} \,:\, x\geq a\}$ is not.

You had to relax the condition $>$ to $\geq$ when you passed to the limit. Similarly, the countable intersection of open sets is (what's called) a [$G_\delta$ set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CE%B4_set). Some $G_\delta$ sets are open, but not all of them and the example you wrote is a perfect illustration of this.

Answer (score 0):

You've picked two odd choices for conditions:

For the first, I'd argue that your *can't* let $n$ go to infinity - the condition changes from $\gt$ to $\ge$. Of course, the condition $\ge$ does allow you to let $n$ go to infinity.

For the second, you *can* let $n$ go to infinity. In fact, an arbitrary union if open sets is still open. Maybe you were thinking of intersections?

Regardless, you have to learn it on a case by case basis. But I will mention that this is sometimes called "continuity", as an analogy with the fact that for a continuous function you can interchange limit and evaluation.